# Specifying a permissions path or Permissions assignment failed for secure file .... 'Got '0o655' instead of '0o0600'

Tags: windows, docker, jupyter-notebook, docker-volume

Based on this [article](https://medium.com/fundbox-engineering/overview-d3759e83969c) to run a docker container with Jupyter Notebook, I got to execute the following command

```
docker run -it  -m 8g -e GRANT_SUDO=yes --user root --rm -p 8888:8888 -p 4040:4040 -v C:/Users/user_name:/home/jovyan jupyter/datascience-notebook
```

which throws the following error

```
Permissions assignment failed for secure file: '/home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-a3592305-5a0e-4cb9-b5ef-3ef74d969538.json'. Got '0o655' instead of '0o0600'.
```

One could get arround this issue if you specify the mounted volume to the container as `/Users/user_name` instead of `C:/Users/user_name`. Is this related to not having the right permissions to write under `C:/any_path`?

Comment: I got something similar and as you said the error dissapears if you put the path that way but I got another errorPermission denied